# How to properly align text to image?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So, I've got this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvG3n/4/) code.

I can't solve this amateur problem. I need to get the images to be right aligned to the text in every single `<li>`. It should be aligned symmetrically, maybe some vertical-align?

I have no idea how to do this, though it's probably easy. Every answer is appreciated.

Comment: What images? There aren't any images in your fiddle...

Comment: Nope. I don't see any either.

Comment: No `img` tags, no images in css, nothing. Perhaps edit your fiddle?

Comment: Maybe now [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvG3n/4/) ?

Comment: I understand, but there has to be a way to do it. Every image will be 90px x 90px and there's some room for text to fit on the right side of #sidebar.

Comment: @user3151531 Check my answer, I believe it fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/cvG3n/13/

Notice that I changed the position of the `<img>` tags to the start of the `<p>` tags. Also I added the following css:

```
img{
float:right;
}
```

If you want the image up higher, put it inside the `<h1>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align `<img>` and `<p>`, you can use this :

```
li p, li img {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/kEC5a/1/)

Comment: Look in the questions comments for the correct fiddle. This isn't what the poster wants.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I was really looking for. I posted an updated version of JSFiddle code to the comments of main post.

Comment: This still looks broken. @user3151531 Check my answer.

Comment: @MathewMacLean Not broken. The picture is align with the text. OP should give a sample.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QEdC5/17/
http://jsfiddle.net/QEdC5/17/show

```
li{
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  float: right; 
  margin: 0 0 0.8em 0.8em;
}
```

Comment: This is far more complicated than it needs to be. See my answer.

Comment: Mine is different. In my example the text does not go under the image. http://jsfiddle.net/EC58F/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/QEdC5/15/

Comment: If you do not clear the parent li the image will not be contained which is floated. http://jsfiddle.net/c787U/3/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/c787U/2/ You need if you want to style the list with separator lines or backgrounds.